# Icons on desktop are corrupt and some are missing in the taskbar

Tags: windows

Check the screenshot here for the issue:

[image: Screenshot]

Here are the technical details of the machine:

- CPU: Intel i7-1165G7
- RAM: 2x 16GB Crucial Ballistix DDR4
- SSD: Kingston SKC2500M8100G 1TB
- Brand: Schenker
- Model: Media 14 (Clevo NV40MB)
- Windows version: Windows 11 22000.2538 (Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22001.1000.0)

The diagnostic tools available in Windows itself found nothing. `sfc.exe` and `chkdsk.exe` looked good and didn't give any found errors. The memory diagnostics found nothing and the general Windows health check app said everything is fine. According to S.M.A.R.T the SSD is fine too, a screenshot created with CrystalDiskInfo is at the end. Here you can find a pastbin containing the details from CPU-Z https://pastebin.com/et6xTdR3

About half a year ago, the laptop got a water damage. Since then the battery is broken, but no swelling occured. My current guess is that the SSD got a few drops on its electronics and S.M.A.R.T just reports wrong data and the SSD is actually broken.

[image: CrystalDiskInfo]

Comment: Not really pixellated - corrupt [I changed your title]. Presumably there's an icon database somewhere that's been corrupted & needs rebuilding. idk Windows well enough to know exactly where to look.

Comment: @Tetsujin Haven't thought of that but good question how to rebuild it.